# Problema con Violación de segmento, a veces funciona y a veces no, mismo prueba y mismo codigo

Tags: c++

Estoy hace dias peleándome con un código el cual estimo tener problemas de memoria y se aprox donde puedo tener el problema, pero no logro identificarlo en si.

El código lo que hace es encontrar una repetición máxima dentro de una cadena y una maximal (es cuando dado una subcadena, esta se repite mas de una vez y si se le agrega un carácter a izquierda o derecha deja de repetirse, o sea, sea la encuentra solo una vez dentro de la cadena)

Haciendo distintas pruebas, puede corroborar que hasta encontrar el maximo funciona correctamente, ahora bien, cuando busco el maximal a veces da Violación de segmento dentro del for que busco los maximales.

```
struct subCadena { 
    int cantApariciones;
    string prefijo;
    vector< pair <int,int> > posicionDeRepeticion;
};

string damePalabra(string secuencia, int desde, int hasta);
pair <int, vector< pair <int,int> >> cantRepeticiones(string secuencia, string subSecuencia);
void  maximo(struct subCadena *subSecuencia, int count);
int tamPalabra(string secuencia);
bool sinRepetidos(struct subCadena *subSecuencia, string cadenaUnitaria, int count);
bool igualdad(string cadenaYaIngresada, string cadenaPorIngresar);
void mostrarHastaPesos(string palabra);
void buscoMaximal(struct subCadena *subSecuenciaSinRep, string secuencia, int count);

int main()
{
    cout << "Ingresar secuencia:" << "\n";


   string secuencia;//En esta variable estará almacenado el nombre ingresado.
   cin >> secuencia; //Se lee el nombre
   int tamSecuencia =0;
   int c=0;
   tamSecuencia = secuencia.length();

   //cuento la cantidad de array necesarios como maximo para separar la cadena
   int count = 0;
   for (int i = 1; i <= tamSecuencia; ++i){
        count = i + count;
   }
    struct subCadena subSecuencia[count];

   //hago partes
   c = 0;
    for (int h = 0; h < tamSecuencia; ++h){
        for (int j = 0; j < tamSecuencia; ++j){
            if (j + h >= tamSecuencia){
                break;
            }
            subSecuencia[c].prefijo = damePalabra(secuencia, h, h+j); 
            c++;
        }
    }


    //busco cantidad de repeticiones de cada particion

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
        subSecuencia[i].cantApariciones = cantRepeticiones(secuencia, subSecuencia[i].prefijo).first;
        subSecuencia[i].posicionDeRepeticion = cantRepeticiones(secuencia, subSecuencia[i].prefijo).second;
    }
    struct subCadena subSecuenciaSinRep[count];
    int cantidadSinRepetidos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
        if (sinRepetidos(subSecuenciaSinRep, subSecuencia[i].prefijo, count)){
            subSecuenciaSinRep[i].prefijo = subSecuencia[i].prefijo;
            subSecuenciaSinRep[i].cantApariciones = subSecuencia[i].cantApariciones;
            subSecuenciaSinRep[i].posicionDeRepeticion = cantRepeticiones(secuencia, subSecuencia[i].prefijo).second;
            mostrarHastaPesos(subSecuenciaSinRep[i].prefijo);
            cout << " Cantidad de apariciones: " << subSecuenciaSinRep[i].cantApariciones << "\n";
        //esto despues hay que sacarlo
            cantidadSinRepetidos++;
        }
    }

    maximo(subSecuencia, count); 
    buscoMaximal(subSecuenciaSinRep, secuencia, cantidadSinRepetidos);
    return 0;
}


string damePalabra(string secuencia, int desde, int hasta){
    int longitud =  hasta-desde+1;
    int count = secuencia.length();
    char palabra[count];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < longitud; ++i){
        //cout << "damePalabra" << "\n";
        palabra[i] =  secuencia[desde+i];
    }
    palabra[i] = '$';
    for (int i = longitud+1; i < count; ++i){
        palabra[i] = ' ';
    }
    return palabra;
}

 pair <int, vector< pair <int,int> >> cantRepeticiones(string secuencia, string subSecuencia){

  int encontrados = 0;
  bool valido = false;
  bool salir = false;
  int c = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int count = secuencia.length();
  vector< pair <int,int> > posicionDeRepeticionTotal;
  pair <int,int> posicionDeRepeticion;
  pair <int, vector< pair <int,int> >> cantidadDeAparicionesConPosicion;
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
    if (subSecuencia[0] == secuencia[i]){
        salir = false;
        valido = true;
        posicionDeRepeticion.first = i;
        if (subSecuencia[1] == '$'){
            valido = false;
            salir = true;
            encontrados++;
            posicionDeRepeticion.second = i;
            posicionDeRepeticionTotal.push_back(posicionDeRepeticion);
        }
        j = i;
        while(valido && !salir){
            c++;
            j++;
            if (subSecuencia[c] != '$'){
                if (subSecuencia[c] != secuencia[j]){
                    valido = false;
                }
            }else{
                encontrados++;
                salir = true;
                posicionDeRepeticion.second = j-1;
                posicionDeRepeticionTotal.push_back(posicionDeRepeticion);
            }
        }
        c = 0;

    }
  }
    cantidadDeAparicionesConPosicion.first = encontrados;
    cantidadDeAparicionesConPosicion.second = posicionDeRepeticionTotal;
    //cout << "palabra: " << subSecuencia << "cantidad: " << encontrados << "\n" ;
    return cantidadDeAparicionesConPosicion;
}

void  maximo(struct subCadena *subSecuencia, int count){
    int max = subSecuencia[0].cantApariciones;
    string palabra = subSecuencia[0].prefijo;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if (max <= subSecuencia[i].cantApariciones){
            max = subSecuencia[i].cantApariciones;
            palabra = subSecuencia[i].prefijo;
        }
    }

    //me quedo con el maximo tanto en repeticiones como en tamaño
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
        if (max == subSecuencia[i].cantApariciones) {
            if (tamPalabra(palabra) < tamPalabra(subSecuencia[i].prefijo)){
                palabra = subSecuencia[i].prefijo;
            }
        }
    }
    std::pair <string,int> palabraMax;
    cout << "Maxima ";
    mostrarHastaPesos(palabra);
    palabraMax.first = palabra;
    palabraMax.second = max; 
    cout << " Cantidad de apariciones: " << max << "\n";

}


void buscoMaximal(struct subCadena *subSecuenciaSinRep, string secuencia, int count){
    std::pair <string,int> palabraMaximal;
    int tamSecuencia = secuencia.length(); 
    int cantidadDeMaximales = 0;
    vector< pair <string,int> > palabrasMaximales;
    bool esMaximal = false;
    bool valido = false;
    int indiceInicial = 0;
    int indiceFinal = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
        //cout << "i: " << i << "\n";
        //cout << "count: " << count << "\n";
        //cout << "palabra: " << subSecuenciaSinRep[i].prefijo << "\n"; 
        if (subSecuenciaSinRep[i].cantApariciones >= 2){
            //es potencial maximal
            esMaximal = true;
            j = 0;
            valido = false;
            while(esMaximal && !valido){
                if (subSecuenciaSinRep[i].posicionDeRepeticion[j].first-1 >=0){
                    indiceInicial = subSecuenciaSinRep[i].posicionDeRepeticion[j].first-1;
                    indiceFinal = subSecuenciaSinRep[i].posicionDeRepeticion[j].second;
                    string palabra = damePalabra(secuencia, indiceInicial, indiceFinal);
                    if (cantRepeticiones(secuencia, palabra).first > 1){
                        //si tengo una cadena con mas de una repeticion no soy maximal
                         esMaximal = false;
                         break;
                    }
                }
                if (subSecuenciaSinRep[i].posicionDeRepeticion[j].second + 1 < tamSecuencia){
                    indiceFinal = subSecuenciaSinRep[i].posicionDeRepeticion[j].second + 1;
                    string palabra = damePalabra(secuencia, subSecuenciaSinRep[i].posicionDeRepeticion[j].first, indiceFinal);
                    if (cantRepeticiones(secuencia, palabra).first > 1){
                        //si tengo una cadena con mas de una repeticion no soy maximal
                         esMaximal = false;
                         break;
                    }
                }
                j++;
                if (j == subSecuenciaSinRep[i].cantApariciones){
                    valido = true;
                }
            }
            if (esMaximal){
                palabraMaximal.first = subSecuenciaSinRep[i].prefijo;
                palabraMaximal.second =  subSecuenciaSinRep[i].cantApariciones;
                palabrasMaximales.push_back(palabraMaximal);
                cantidadDeMaximales++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidadDeMaximales; ++i){
        cout << "Maximal " ;
        mostrarHastaPesos(palabrasMaximales[i].first);
        cout << "\n";
    }

}
```

Saludos

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. Poca genta estará dispuesta a revisarte **mas de 220 líneas**, y de un código que claramente está incompleto y **no compilará**. ¿ Te has pasado por el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) ? ¿ Y por [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, deberías revisar lo que es un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: También, intenta colocar las etiquetas adecuadas. ¿ Que versión de C++ estás usando ? ¿ 98, 11 o 17 ? Y el editor que usas, dev-c++, no tiene **absolutamente nada que ver** con tu problema.

Comment: Estás utilizando formaciones de tamaño variable (lee [estos hilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=c+c%2B%2B+vla) para saber más). Lo cuál no está permitido en C++ salvo por extensiones del compilador.

Answer (score 1):

No sé como compila el programa, tal vez si lo resumiste te hayas olvidado algo.

Lo primero que veo es esto:

```
struct subCadena subSecuencia[count];
char palabra[count];
```

Una declaración de array es cualquier declaración simple cuyo declarador de array tiene la forma:

```
declarador-nopuntero [ expr(opcional) ] atrib(opcional)
```

expr    -   una expresión constante entera (hasta C++14)una expresión constante convertida de tipo std::size_t (desde C++14), que se evalúa a un valor mayor que cero

Revisa este [link](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) para entender como inicializar un array

[mas ayuda](http://c.conclase.net/curso/?cap=010)

Una variable de tipo char es un array de caracteres. Por lo que se inicializa igual que un array.

Lo primero que recomiendo es que si no sabes que tamaño tendra el array utilices un array dinámico, es decir, std::vector, también puedes hacer un vector que contenga char(std::vector < char > ) o mejor std::string.

Siempre que recorras un vector asegurate de no salirte del rango de elementos que posee, estoy seguro que los errores de violación de memoria son por salirse del rango y tratar de acceder un elemento del array mayor al tamaño del array configurado, o por eliminar un caracter de la cadena y continuar recorriendola.

con [std::string](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) puedes utilizar funciones como [insert](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) para la maximal y [find](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Comment: La declaración del array `subSecuencia` es sintácticamente correcta, pero obsoleta. Dado que `subCadena` es una `struct`, pueden declararse variables de ese tipo con `struct subCadena nombre;` aunque sea código válido, es una forma obsoleta de declaración remanente de [tag:c], no es necesario añadir el `struct`.